# Calculate difference between times in results SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datediff

I have a table with results:

```
C_EventTime        L_TID
20130228162022     27200
20130228162059     27200
```

How would I calculate difference in seconds between the two?
In the end, I need to calculate all the differences to make a total for the month.

I've tried:

```
declare @startdt  '20130228162022'
declare @enddt    '20140101000001'

set @startdt =  cast('20130101000001' as datetime) 
set @enddt   =  cast('20140101000001' as datetime)  

SELECT DATEDIFF(C_EventTime) FROM tTerminalStateLog
WHERE C_EventTime BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate
and L_TID = 27200
```

but suspect with my limited SQL knowledge I'm way off! Any help appreciated.
Tx

Comment: [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) takes 3 arguments, not one.  How do you know what two values you want to compare?

Answer (score 0):

The strings you are using, don't convert nicely to a valid datetime format.

Credit to http://rdineshkumar.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-convert-yyyymmddhhmmss-to-datetimedatetime-in-sql-server/ for the formula here.

First off, `DATEDIFF()` takes 3 arguments.  The return value, be it seconds, days, etc.  Then the start/end dates.  Ex `DATEDIFF(SS,startdate,enddate)` [Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

Here is a sample on how to convert your two start/end values to a datetime, and calculate the difference between them.

```
declare @startdt datetime
declare @enddt datetime

select @startdt =
Convert(time,Dateadd(SECOND,
        Right('20130228162022',2)/1,
        Dateadd(MINUTE,
                Right('20130228162022',4)/100,
                Dateadd(hour,
                        Right('20130228162022',6)/10000,
                        '1900-01-01')))) +
convert(datetime,LEFT('20130228162022',8))

select @enddt =
Convert(time,Dateadd(SECOND,
        Right('20140101000001',2)/1,
        Dateadd(MINUTE,
                Right('20140101000001',4)/100,
                Dateadd(hour,
                        Right('20140101000001',6)/10000,
                        '1900-01-01')))) +
convert(datetime,LEFT('20140101000001',8))

select @startdt, @enddt
select DATEDIFF(ss, @startdt, @enddt)
```

However your table shows the values split into separate rows...  This makes it slightly more complicated.

Assuming you have 2 results per L_Tid (no more, or this won't work) and you always want to compare the oldest-to-newest date (they'll never write backwards), you could do this:

```
declare @tTerminalStateLog table (C_EventTime varchar(15), L_Tid INT)

insert into @tTerminalStateLog 
select '20130228162022',27200 union all
select '20130228162059',27200

declare @startdt varchar(15), @enddt varchar(15)
set @startdt = '20130228162022'
set @enddt =  '20140101000001'

; with datesdata as 
(
SELECT Convert(time,Dateadd(SECOND,
        Right(C_EventTime,2)/1,
        Dateadd(MINUTE,
                Right(C_EventTime,4)/100,
                Dateadd(hour,
                        Right(C_EventTime,6)/10000,
                        '1900-01-01')))) +
        convert(datetime,LEFT(C_EventTime,8)) myDate,
        L_Tid,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(order by C_EventTime) as myID
FROM @tTerminalStateLog
WHERE C_EventTime BETWEEN @startdt and @enddt
and L_Tid=27200
)

select d1.myDate, d2.myDate, DATEDIFF(ss, d1.myDate, d2.myDate) [sec_diff]
from datesdata d1
left outer join datesdata d2 
   on d1.L_Tid=d2.L_Tid 
   and d2.myID=2
where d1.myID=1
```